# Limit of a function with three variables.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Let
> $$f(x,y,z) = \frac{(x+y+z-3)^3}{z^3(x-1)(y-2)}.$$
> I want the limit for this function as $(x,y,z)$ approaches $(1,2,0)$.

It was a given that this limit does exist, but by going at it from $(1,2,z)$, I get the same thing as from $(x,2,0)$ and $(1,y,0)$, so how do I know that that's not where the function goes to as it approaches $(1,2,0)$?

What are the other ways that I can evaluate this limit in order for it to be proven to not exist?

Comment: Use [This guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) perhaps

Comment: If you **pretend** to edit your posting, by taking the *edit* link, you will have access to the MathJax syntax used by Robert Z to present the math in your posting.

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: You claim to have tried to approach the limit point along three separate curves. Why not show the result of those attempts?

Answer (score 2):

$f(x,y,z) = \frac{(x+y+z-3)^3}{z^3(x-1)(y-2)}$ is **NOT** defined on those 3 curves, so it is not meaningful to talk about the limit along these curves.

To prove $\lim\limits_{(x,y,z)\to (1,2,0)}f(x,y,z)$ does not exist, you are only required to show the limit along any one curve approach $(1,2,0)$ does not exist.

Along the curve $x=1+t$,$y=2+t$,$z=-t$,
as $t\to 0$, $(x,y,z)\to (1,2,0)$, and

$\lim\limits_{(x,y,z)\to (1,2,0)}f(x,y,z)=\lim\limits_{t\to 0} \frac{-1}{t^2}$ which does not exist.